# SonarLint quick find Critical issues

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

In SonarLint for IntelliJ IDEA,
on the **Project files** tab,
selecting **All project files** as **Scope**,
how can I locate *Critical* or *Blocker* issues quickly?

Answer (score 2):

This feature shows the issues in the entire project grouped by file, where files are sorted in alphabetic order, and for each file, the issues are listed in decreasing order of severity. But probably you're looking for something more.

Currently it's not possible to filter or customize the output of this feature.
You could request for such feature on the mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarlint